# Shortest path calculation

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, algorithms, polygons

I have a given set of start points, a given set of end points. Each start point corresponds to one endpoint. I have to visit all start points, and then the corresponding end points, in the most optimal way( in the way that the path is the shortest). What algorithm will you suggest me to use?

Thanks much in advance

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand the question. We have a weighted graph $G = (V,E)$. $V$ contains two disjoint subsets $S$ and $T$, a set of starts and terminals, and we have some bijective destination function $d: S \leftrightarrow T$, such that $d(s)$ gives the terminal corresponding to the start point $s$. Are you then looking for the shortest path from each $s \in S$ to $d(s)$? Are you looking for a path that starts at some $s_1 \in S$, travels to $d(s_1)$, then travels to $s_2$, then to $d(s_2)$, etc? Are you looking for some other path?

Comment: Thank you!!! I have to visit all start points once, then I have to visit all the end points once( each startpoint has the corresponding end point, that has to be visited). I want the way to do it in the shortest way( the shortest path)

Comment: Thus, in what order may be to pick the start points, and the end points, to get the shortest path

Comment: And you want to do this on a single path? So not only must you travel from $s_1$ to $d(s_1)$, but you must also travel from $d(s_1)$ to $s_2$? Or do I need to traverse all start points first, and then traverse all end points?

Comment: First all start points need to be visited, then we go to the optimal first end point, than to the second, until all endpoints are visited, exactly once

Comment: Thank you much for your help

Comment: Just a small suggestion))

Comment: Here is what I understand. You have two groups of vertices. The first group has to be visited first, then you visit the second group. Your objective is to minimize the total distance. Am I on the right track?

Comment: yes, you are right. I want to visit 2 groups of vertices, first start points( every vertice is visited once), then endpoints( every endpoint visited once). Every startpoint corresponds to endpoint, that has to be visited. I want to minimize the total distance

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-complete. If you do find a good algorithm for solving it, please tell me.

Let $G = (V,w)$ be an instance of the Non-returning Travelling Salesman Problem with vertex set $V$, and weight function $w$. We seek the shortest path that travels through every point in $V$ with respect to $w$. If two vertices $(u,v)$ do not have an edge between them, we will represent this by saying $w(u,v) = \infty$.

We will construct an instance of your problem whose solution can be decoded into a solution to the Non-returning Travelling Salesman Problem. Let $S = V$, and $T$ be an arbitrary set, disjoint from $S$, such that $|S| = |T|$. Let $w': S \cup T \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ such that

$$
w'(u,v) = 
\begin{cases}
w(u,v) &\mbox{for } u,v \in S\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

So in the graph $(S \cup T, w')$, travelling between points in $S$ is just as expensive as before, travelling from anywhere in $S$ to anywhere in $T$ is free, and travelling within $T$ is free. Let $d: S \leftrightarrow T$ be an arbitrary destination function.

Suppose we had a "fast" algorithm to solve your problem with start points $S$, terminals $T$, destination function $d$ and weight function $w'$. This solution would give us the shortest path that passes through all points in $S$, followed by some path through $T$. Taking only the section of the path that travels through $S$, we will now have the shortest Hamiltonian path through $V$ with weight function $w$, which is the solution to the non-returning Travelling Salesman Problem.

The travelling salesman problem reduces in polynomial time to your problem, so your problem is NP-complete, so, assuming P $\neq$ NP, no good algorithm for solving it exists.